# Copy a complete chat from whatsapp to PC

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Anyone an idea how I can download a complete conversation with voice messages and pictures to an xls file with date and time? I can do it manualy by copy paste and save every individual voice message but that is a lot of work. Can this be done on another way?
Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the conversation. Enter options menu -> more -> export chat -> with media -> send via email
2. Check your email. Save all attachments to disk.
3. Open the text file with Wordpad. Press CTRL + H. Replace string `- Name 1:` with the string `|Name 1|` and repeat for `Name 2`. Save it.
4. Open spreadsheet, and use `|` as separator, when importing a text file.